# Can someone explain about M-theory?

Tags: thermodynamics, string-theory, quantum-gravity

1. Can someone explain about [M-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory)?

I am very new to M-theory and string theory. I am very through with classical physics and little bits of quantum mechanics.

2. Will you be able to explain why the fact that gravity is a weak force being a very important factor for the success of this theory.
3. How much does this theory hold against the second law of thermodynamics that is the entropy of the universe?

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're asking. What has the second law to do with M-theory or gravity being a weak force? What *exactly* do you want to know?

Comment: " I am very through with classical physics and little bits of quantum mechanics."

You should really gain a solid understanding of GR and QFT before attempting to learn String Theory.

Answer (score 2):

First let us cut away some of the meat and the bones of your question.  Let us forget about thermodynamics for a minute and classical physics; however we will need GRAVITY (not Newton’s version).  Instead of calling it Gravity let us call it General Relativity or (GR).  We can still use the term Gravity, but when discussing Quantum Mechanics it’s better to see it as Einstein’s theory of General Relativity (not to be confused with Special Relativity).

General Relativity at its best is the idea that we experience what we know as Gravity, not because of some invisible ethereal force like Newton thought, but rather because space is curved. GR is illustrated (yet exaggerate) in the movie Interstellar when they are discussing the different levels of gravity and time dilation on different planets (or being near a black hole).  Moreover Gravity warps space and time.  This further leads us to why it is important to M-Theory.

Well, M-theory is the mother lode of all string theory THEORIES and it posits that the entire universe is made up strings that vibrate in one dimension in an 11 dimensions universe!   That one dimension was generalized as length.  These STRINGS in fact are a different view on particle physics altogether; where the point-like particles in the Quantum realm are replaced by the strings.   We also know from particle physics that particles do not follow the rules of General Relativity (since Einstein only was thinking of Gravity in only three dimension when he came up with the theory).  Hence the need for a theory of Supergravity is needed to help understand the behavior of strings.

This unification could completely overturn Einstein’s theory of Gravity (GR).  Think if we truly understood Gravity beyond GR we may just understand greater means of propelling ourselves off this planet and into interstellar travel.

This is just, a rough sketch (extremely rough) and I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Coyote Gunnyon